# Xcode stopped auto-indenting

Tags: xcode, xcode4

When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in Xcode 4, the cursor ends up at the beginning of the next line instead of indenting it as the previous line. I don't remember doing anything that could cause this, such as modifying any editor preference or anything like that.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Sounds odd! Have you tried moving your Xcode prefs aside and seeing what happens?

Comment: @user1118321, I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: They're in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist and ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.LSSharedFileList.plist. You can simply quit Xcode, move those files to your desktop, or somewhere like that, and re-launch Xcode and see if it still happens. If it doesn't happen anymore, then it may mean your prefs got corrupt somehow. If it still happens, then it's not related to your prefs, and you can move them back.

Comment: OK, I've added it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your Xcode prefs aside and seeing what happens. They're in

- `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist`
- `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.LSSharedFileList.plist`

You can simply quit Xcode, move those files to your desktop, or somewhere like that, and re-launch Xcode and see if it still happens. If it doesn't happen anymore, then it may mean your prefs got corrupt somehow. If it still happens, then it's not related to your prefs, and you can move them back.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. This was happening because the following option was checked: "Automatically trim whitespace → Including whitespace-only lines". I'm using the latest Xcode 4.5 preview release. Hopefully this will be fixed in the final release.

Answer (score 0):

For me, restarting Xcode after clearing trash and derived data worked!